# Error "unexpected indent"

Tags: python

El siguiente código es para una tarea , alguien me puede ayudar , en el código están los comentarios con los errores. Muchas gracias

```
print("Bienvenidos al sistema de ubicacion de zonas publicas wifi")
```

```py
nombredeusuario ="emanuel" #Este nombre de usuario esta por defecto

password = "12345" #Contraseña por defecto

usuarioingresado = input("Ingrese Nombre de Usuario:", " ")

if usuarioingresado == nombredeusuario:

    contraseñaingresada=input("Ingrese Contraseña:", " ")

        if contraseñaingresada == password: #Me indica un unexpected indent

            if usuarioingresado == nombredeusuario and contraseñaingresada == password:
                
                resultadoCaptcha = int(input('cuanto es' + password[2]  + ' + 9'))
                if resultadoCaptcha == int(password[2]) + 9:
                    print('ingreso exitoso')
                else:
                    print("Captcha incorrecto")
            else:
                print("Ingreso exitoso")
        else:
            print("Error")
else: 
    print("Error") #En este else también tengo errores
```

Comment: indenta bien tu codigo

Comment: el segundo `if` debe estar a la altura de la variable `contraseñaingresada`

Comment: jksjkjs editaste la publicación y de una le arreglaste el problema xD

Comment: @AnkiJedi no toque nada del codigo solo le puse el formato :)

Comment: true, el segundo if sigue igual x'd

Answer (score 0):

Error “unexpected indent”, este error suele pasar cuando hay alguna línea de el código que esta mal indentada, debes indentar bien tu código, y en alguna ocaciones pasa que esta ya indentado el código, pero debes borrar esos espacios de la indentación y volver a poner los espacios de indentación, y de esa manera podrás dar solución.

```
print("Bienvenidos al sistema de ubicacion de zonas publicas wifi")
nombredeusuario ="emanuel" #Este nombre de usuario esta por defecto

password = "12345" #Contraseña por defecto

usuarioingresado = input("Ingrese Nombre de Usuario:", " ")

if usuarioingresado == nombredeusuario:

    contraseñaingresada=input("Ingrese Contraseña:", " ")
```

#esta linea y la siguiente linea deben ir alineadas, ese es tu error.

```
    if contraseñaingresada == password: #Me indica un unexpected indent

        if usuarioingresado == nombredeusuario and contraseñaingresada == password:
            
            resultadoCaptcha = int(input('cuanto es' + password[2]  + ' + 9'))
            if resultadoCaptcha == int(password[2]) + 9:
                print('ingreso exitoso')
            else:
                print("Captcha incorrecto")
        else:
            print("Ingreso exitoso")
    else:
        print("Error")
else: 
    print("Error") #En este else también tengo errores
```

Espero te sirva.